# Getting a single file from a tar file using the tarfile lib in python

Tags: python, tarfile

I am trying to grab a single file from a tar archive.  I have the tarfile library and I can do things like find the file in a list with the right extension:

like their example:

```
def xml_member_files(self,members): 
    for tarinfo in members:
        if os.path.splitext(tarinfo.name)[1] == ".xml":
            yield tarinfo


    member_file = self.xml_member_files(tar)
    for m in member_file:           
        print m.name
```

This is great and the output is:

```
RS2_C0RS2_OK67683_PK618800_DK549742_SLA23_20151006_234046_HH_SLC/lutBeta.xml
RS2_C0RS2_OK67683_PK618800_DK549742_SLA23_20151006_234046_HH_SLC/lutGamma.xml
RS2_C0RS2_OK67683_PK618800_DK549742_SLA23_20151006_234046_HH_SLC/lutSigma.xml
RS2_C0RS2_OK67683_PK618800_DK549742_SLA23_20151006_234046_HH_SLC/product.xml
```

If I say just look for product.xml then it doesn't work.  So I tried this:

```
    ti = tar.getmember('product.xml')
    print ti.name
```

and it doesn't find product.xml because I am guessing the path information before hand.  I have no idea how to retrieve just that pathing information so I can get at my product.xml file once extracted (feels like I am doing things the hard way anyway) but yah, how do I figure out just that path so I can concatenate it to my other file functions to read and load that xml file after it is the only file extracted from a tar file?

Comment: Please review my answer below, and upvote or mark as as accepted if it helped you in thinking through the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return full path by iterating over result of `getnames()`. For example, to get full path for `lutBeta.xml`:

```
tar = tarfile.TarFile('mytarfile.tar')
membername = [x for x in tar.getnames() if os.path.basename(x) == 'lutBeta.xml'][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try first doing `TarFile.getnames()`, which I imagine works a lot like `tar tzf filename.tar.gz` from the command line. Then you get find out what paths to feed to your getmember() or getmembers().

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be iterating over the entire tar with `getnames()`, `getmember()` or `getmembers()`, because as soon as you find your file, you don't need to keep looking through the rest of the tar.

for example, it takes my machine about 47ms to extract a single file from a 2GB tar by iterating over all the file names:

```py
with tarfile.open('/tmp/2GB-file.tar', mode='r:') as tar:
    membername = [x for x in tar.getnames() if x.endswith('myfile.txt')][0]
    file = tar.extractfile(membername).read().decode()
```

But stopping as soon as the file is found takes me only 0.27 ms, nearly 175x faster.

```py
file = None
with tarfile.open('/tmp/2GB-file.tar', mode='r:') as tar:
    for member in tar:
        if member.name.endswith('myfile.txt'):
            file = tar.extractfile(member).read().decode()
            break
```

Note if the file you need is more near the end of the archive, you probably won't notice much of a change in speed, but it is still a good practice to not loop through the whole file if you don't have to.